# Is it possible to make an array of arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I need to make an array, in which each object is a NSArray:

```
 NSMutableArray *AberdeenStores=[NSMutableArray alloc];

AberdeenStores=[AberdeenStores initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 1",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 1",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 1","", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 2",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 2",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 2", nil],[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 3",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 3",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 3", nil], nil];
```

This seems causing crash. What is wrong please? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a typo in there. Replace "" with @"" in the first sub-array

```
NSMutableArray *AberdeenStores=[NSMutableArray alloc];

AberdeenStores=[AberdeenStores initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 1",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 1",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 1",@"", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 2",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 2",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 2", nil],[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 3",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 3",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 3", nil], nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, i didn't see it, thanx ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more scalable solution:

```
// Top Level Array
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int size = 10;    

// Build sub level arrays
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:subArray];
}

// You can now use it like this:
[[array objectAtIndex:0] addObject:someObject];
NSObject *someObject = [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're using variables and objects and all sorts wrong here. This is the best way to do what you're trying to do and will layout nicely and be better for maintainability.

```
NSMutableArray *AberdeenStores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[AberdeenStores addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 1",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 1",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 1",@"", nil]];
[AberdeenStores addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aberdeen Name Store 2",@"Aberdeen Adress Store 2",@"Aberdeen Telephone store 2",@"", nil]];
[AberdeenStores addObject:... keep adding objects as you please];
```